# SQL Auto cut-off Period Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Below is a list of attendance in a table. Every Month i would need to monitor the attendance based on the cut-off period starting 20/previous month - 19/current month.

```
  Date       Branch      Attendance
13/04/2017  Branch A         5
14/04/2017  Branch A         5
22/04/2017  Branch A         5
30/04/2017  Branch A         5
17/05/2017  Branch A         6
18/05/2017  Branch A         6
01/04/2017  Branch B         17
15/04/2017  Branch B         14
20/04/2017  Branch B         14
19/05/2017  Branch B         17
20/05/2017  Branch B         15
25/05/2017  Branch B         17
```

For Example; I would like to show in a Month of May,where the cut-off period will be 20/4/2017 - 19/5/2017. 
Below are my code:

```
SELECT
  CONVERT(VARCHAR,Date,103) AS Date, 
  Branch, 
  Attendance
FROM 
  Table_attd
WHERE 
  Date>=DATEADD(DAY,(SELECT DATEDIFF (DAY,(DATEADD(DAY,0,GETEDATE())),
       (DATEADD(MONTH,-1,CONVERT(DATETIME,CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS 
       VARCHAR)+'/'+CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS 
       VARCAHR)+'/'+'19',102))))),GETDATE())
       AND Date<=DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE())
```

The results:

```
  Date       Branch  Attendance
22/04/2017  Branch A    5
30/04/2017  Branch A    5
17/05/2017  Branch A    6
18/05/2017  Branch A    6
20/04/2017  Branch B    14
19/05/2017  Branch B    17
```

But I realized that my code has a flaw where When the month of Jun (cut-off period will be 20/5/2017 - 19/6/2017), it result will be incorrect.
Kindly advice - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not a correct syntax, you could use this

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate date = getdate()
DECLARE @20PreviousMonth date  = dateadd(day,19,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,@CurrentDate) - 1,0))
DECLARE @19CurrentMonth date  = dateadd(day,18,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,@CurrentDate) ,0))

SELECT
     CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Date],103) AS Date, 
     Branch, 
     Attendance
FROM 
    Table_attd
WHERE 
    [Date] BETWEEN @20PreviousMonth AND @19CurrentMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ...where [date] between dateadd(day, 19, dateadd(month, -1, cast(convert(char(6), getdate(), 112) + '01' as date))) 
and dateadd(day, 18, cast(convert(char(6), getdate(), 112) + '01' as date))
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to solve this is to create a 'Date' table .

```
Date       CalendarMonth ReportingMonth
2017-19-05 May           May     
2017-20-05 May           June
```

Then simply left join this table to your fact table and group by 'ReportingMonth.'  This allows you to quickly call on data from any time period, and allows for flexibility in the cut-over date.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this.

```
        DECLARE @previous DATETIME = CAST(DATEADD(DAY,
                                                  ( DATEDIFF(DAY,
                                                          ( DATEADD(DAY, 0,
                                                          GETDATE()) ),
                                                          ( DATEADD(MONTH,
                                                          -1,
                                                          CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)
                                                          + '/'
                                                          + CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)
                                                          + '/' + '19', 102)) )) ),
                                                  GETDATE()) AS DATE)

        DECLARE @current DATETIME = CAST(DATEADD(DAY,
                                                 ( DATEDIFF(DAY,
                                                          ( DATEADD(DAY, 0,
                                                          GETDATE()) ),
                                                          ( DATEADD(MONTH,
                                                          0,
                                                          CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)
                                                          + '/'
                                                          + CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)
                                                          + '/' + '20', 102)) )) ),
                                                 GETDATE()) AS DATE)




        SELECT  [Date],
                Branch ,
                Attendance
        FROM    ( SELECT    CONVERT(VARCHAR, Date, 103) AS [Date] ,
                            Branch ,
                            Attendance
                  FROM      Table_attd
                ) T
        WHERE   ( t.Date >= @previous
                  AND t.Date <= @current
                )
```